# How can I trigger file generation via command line WINDOWS?

Tags: doxygen

I have created a configuration file for doxygen, but I don’t know how to trigger the generation of documentation via cmd

Comment: Which version of doxygen? In the directory with the doxygen configuration file (`Doxyfile`) just give the command `doxygen` (assuming you have `doxygen` installed and in your `PATH`)

Comment: Have you read [the manual](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/starting.html)?